# Xcode 11.2.1(11B53) @import FBSDKCoreKit error

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, fbsdk

Xcode version 11.2.1(11B53)

My pod file is here;

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'OnlineHeadBall2' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Bolts'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'Adjust'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
  pod 'Branch', '= 0.29.3'

  #core SDK
  pod 'AMRSDK', '~> 1.4'
  #mediation adapters

  pod 'AMRAdapterAdcolony', '~> 4.1'
  pod 'AMRAdapterAdmob', '~> 7.51'
  pod 'AMRAdapterAdmost', '~> 1.2'
  pod 'AMRAdapterFacebook', '~> 5.6'
  pod 'AMRAdapterHyprmx', '~> 5.2'
  pod 'AMRAdapterIronsource', '~> 6.8'
  pod 'AMRAdapterMintegral', '~> 5.8'
  pod 'AMRAdapterMytarget', '~> 5.3'
  pod 'AMRAdapterQumpara', '~> 1.1'
  pod 'AMRAdapterTapjoy', '~> 12.3'
  pod 'AMRAdapterTiktok', '~> 2.3'
  pod 'AMRAdapterUnity', '~> 3.3'
  pod 'AMRAdapterVungle', '~> 6.4'

end
```

When I try to "Archive" my project, an error occurs; 
**Use of '@import' when C++ modules are disabled, consider using -fmodules and -fcxx-modules**

What can I do for building my project successfully?

[image: Error ScreenShot]

Comment: Your Facebook dependencies are very old. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/implement-the-sdk#cocoapods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add -fcxx-modules to Build Settings->Other C++ Flags->Debug and Release fields.

[image]